# How to wire light switch separate line/load Wires to single wire

Tags: wiring, light

My existing Light switch died and I’m looking to replace with a different brand.   My wall has separate line and separate load wires. And the switch I purchased has a single wire labeled load/line How do I connect?
Here's a link to the new switch
https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07ZSQ8R85/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

See picture of old switch attached[image]

Comment: What's the new switch? Would you be able to link to a manual/product description for it?

Comment: Let us know more about the new replacement switch. If it's another smart switch, a link to the product manual or a photo of the new device will be helpful.

Comment: Here's a link to the new switch - Treatlife x002dozjit . on back of switch it says intertek 
 5012525 
 https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07ZSQ8R85/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: A gray wire for load, that looks fishy.

Comment: Does anyone have any info on why it’s grey. Also why two shades for the neutral wires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch you purchased is a three way switch. Three way circuits have a line at one switch and a load at the other switch which is why you have a line/load wire. You need a switch with a separate line and load terminal/wire. Check your instructions or post them to your question. You use one of the travelers for the load connection.

Comment: thanks, will this work with my wiring     https://smile.amazon.com/Kasa-Smart-Light-Switch-TP-Link/dp/B01EZV35QU/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=single+toggle+smart+switch&qid=1596838067&sr=8-3

Comment: This is a single pole and will work but be careful of buying electrical stuff from amazon. Much of their stuff is junk. Stick with the known brands.

Comment: what brands would you recommend, that's not too expensive

Comment: @Chaim  Check out the brands in your big home stores, Leviton, Lutron, Phillips, etc. I've got no business relationships with any of these.